# how to return queryset as a list on seperate lines, without the brackets

Tags: python, django, string, django-queryset

I have my model for my lessons:

```
class Lessons(models.Model):
student = models.ForeignKey(Students, 
on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True) 

headed_by = models.ForeignKey(Tutors, 
on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
day = models.CharField(max_length=4, 

choices=DAY_CHOICES, null=True)

start_time = models.TimeField(null=True, 
 blank=True)

type  = models.CharField(max_length=7, 
choices=TYPE_CHOICES, null=True)

price_band  = models.CharField(max_length=7, 
choices=PAYMENT_TYPE_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)

created  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True )


def __str__(self):
    return str(self.student) + " at " + 
str(self.start_time)+ " on " + str(self.day)
class Meta:
    ordering=['student',"headed_by",'day','start_time']
```

I have my Query set:

```
tn_mon     = 
Lessons.objects.all().filter(headed_by__name="Tutor 
Name").filter(day__icontains="Mon")
```

which returns

```
<QuerySet [<Lessons:Studentname1 at Time on Day>,
<Lessons:Studentname2 at Time on Day>
```

how can i return the output without the queryset, ,<> []
so that it returns as set out like below?

```
Studentname1 at Time on Day,
Studentname2 at Time on Day
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just loop through queryset and call `str()` on each object

```py
for obj in tn_mon:
   print(str(obj))
```

**OR**
store the obj in `list`

```py
tn_mon_list = []
for obj in tn_mon:
   tn_mon_list.append(str(obj))
```

Comment: Can the loop be stored to be called again at a later date?

Comment: In your case, you can append the `str(obj)` in `list` and use it when required. I have edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
tn_mon = Lessons.objects.all().filter(headed_by__name="Tutor 
Name").filter(day__icontains="Mon").values()

#convert this object it into list
my_list = list(tn_mon)

#If you iterate list
for i in my_list:
 print(i)

Then you will get this
output:
Studentname1 at Time on Day,
Studentname2 at Time on Day
```

If you want Json Response then simply convert it into a Dictionary list

```
data = []
    for i in my_list:
        data.append(i)
return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Comment: How can I store the output of the loop? 
So that I can call it in the same way as I did with tj_mon

Comment: @Sandip Mahto, `str` method of obj needed not just object.Your answer will print `<Lessons:Studentname1 at Time on Day>`